# Use Python decorator to handle try and exception

Tags: python, decorator

How to pass try function and exception handler function in decorator way

For example, this is the `WCF` connection.

```
def wcf():
    def send_request(result):
        # establish connection...
        result["response"] = True

    def handle_execption(e, result):
        # logger something
        result["error"] = str(e)
    result = {}
    try:
        send_request(result)
    except Exception as e:
        handle_execption(e, result)
```

Now, I want to add a retry mechanism to this connection.
What is the best way to achieve that, I have multiple connection ways(like `REST`, `SOAP` `WCF`, etc)? In general, they share the same pattern and all have the `send_request` and `handle_execption`.

The hard-code one is like the following, but it's quite silly to add the same logic to every protocol.

```
for attempt in range(0, 3):
    sleep_seconds = attempt ** 2
    sleep(sleep_seconds)

    try:
        send_request(result)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        handle_execption(e, result)
```

Comment: You don't have to increase attempt in the for loop, as well as using if statement to sleep

Comment: Oh, you are right, thanks @AlexanderGolys

Comment: Shouldn't `result` be a `dict` instead of a list, i.e. `result = {}` instead of `result = []`?

Comment: @md2perpe, exactly.... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always handle exceptions in the same way, you can write a decorator that hardcodes that behavior and handles the retrying logic:

```
def retry_decorator(base_function):
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):  # This allows you to decorate functions without worrying about what arguments they take
        for attempt in range(3):
            sleep_seconds = attempt ** 2
            sleep(sleep_seconds)

            try:
                return base_function(*args, **kwargs)  # base_function is whatever function this decorator is applied to
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)  # Replace this with whatever you want, as long as it's the same for all possible base_functions

    return new_function


@retry_decorator  # Replaces send_request() with retry_decorator(send_request)()
def send_request(result):
    result["response"] = True
```

If you want to use different exception handling logic for the different connections, things get a bit more complicated:

```
def retry_decorator_2(exception_handle_function):
    def new_decorator(base_function):
        def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for attempt in range(3):
                sleep_seconds = attempt ** 2
                sleep(sleep_seconds)

                try:
                    return base_function(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    exception_handle_function(e)

        return new_function

    return new_decorator


@retry_decorator_2(print)  # Replace 'print' with an exception handling function
def send_request(result):
    result["response"] = True
```

In this case, `retry_decorator_2(print)` creates a new decorator (which stores `print` as the `exception_handle_function`), then applies that decorator to the `send_request` function.

If you need the `exception_handle_function` to take arguments, you can pass them as part of the decorator:

```
def retry_decorator_3(exception_handle_function, *exception_function_args, **exception_function_kwargs):
    def new_decorator(base_function):
        def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
            for attempt in range(3):
                sleep_seconds = attempt
                sleep(sleep_seconds)

                try:
                    return base_function(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    exception_handle_function(e, *exception_function_args, **exception_function_kwargs)

        return new_function

    return new_decorator


@retry_decorator_3(print, 1, 2, 3)  # 1, 2, 3 become arguments for the print function, or whatever you replace it with
def send_request(result):
    result["response"] = True
```

Comment: This is awesome, one more question. What if we want to pass arguments into `exception_handle_function`? @water_ghosts

Answer (score 0):

Why decorator? I think that it's just as clean with

```py
def wcf():
    def send_request(result):
        # establish connection...
        result["response"] = True

    def handle_exception(e, result):
        # logger something
        result["error"] = str(e)

    return retry(send_request, handle_exception)


def retry(send_request, handle_exception):
    result = {}

    for attempt in range(0, 3):
        sleep(attempt ** 2)

        try:
            send_request(result)
            return result

        except Exception as e:
            return handle_execption(e, result)
```

Comment: That is a good point. If we are being stubborn and for learning perspective, do you know how to rewrite them as decorator?